# Ways to display money in python without using the decimal package

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I want to have Python declare a `float` variable and then display that variable to two decimal points, *even* if the number is an integer. For example:

```
def floatToMoney:
    # Some kind of function that outputs two decimal places
foo = float(6)
print(floatToMoney(foo))
boo = float(3.14159)
print(floatToMoney(boo))
```

and have an output of:

```
6.00
3.14
```

I know that `round()` can do this, but again if the number is an integer it doesn't display the decimal places. I found the `decimal` package, but is there any way to do this without having to import any packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.x and 2.7, you can simply do this:

```
>>> '${:,.2f}'.format(1234.5)
'$1,234.50'
```

The :, adds a comma as a thousands separator, and the .2f limits the string to two decimal places (or adds enough zeroes to get to 2 decimal places, as the case may be) at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just use a format string:

```
def floatToMoney(f):
    return "%.2f" % f
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. I haven't really used % in python strings before, so I don't know how they work. Could you please explain? Thank you!